# convert currency in whole page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

Wanted to convert Currency amount in whole webpage as we select from dropdown 'USD', 'IND'. By default currency is in INR.

[image]

Comment: Okay, so what have you tried? Can you show us a sample of your code?

Comment: Please share the relevant code too.

Comment: I am even searching concept to do the same :|

Answer (score 1):

You have two possible options:

- changing the dropbox value causes the whole webside to reload with the new currency or
- changing the dropbox value does a ajax call to reload all prices and then replace them with javascript

depends on your choise, what way to go ;)

Comment: I can think of atleast 10 other methods to change currency withour reloading. Just depends on how your site is build and without that information, you cant realy answer this

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple PHP code, using which you can get the live currency Value from yahoo finance ( http://finance.yahoo.com/ )

In this example i am getting the value of US Dollar in Indian Rupees.

```
<?php
$from   = 'USD'; /*change it to your required currencies */
$to     = 'INR';
$url = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?e=.csv&f=sl1d1t1&s='. $from . $to .'=X';
$handle = @fopen($url, 'r');

if ($handle) {
    $result = fgets($handle, 4096);
    fclose($handle);
}
$allData = explode(',',$result); /* Get all the contents to an array */
$dollarValue = $allData[1];

echo 'Value of $1 in Indian Rupees is Rs. '.$dollarValue;
?>
```

Comment: @Sagar Shinde Please don't forget to make it up vote if it's use full

Comment: @yeah sure..but unfortunately my reputation on stack overflow is not enough to do so.. but thanks a lot :)